# Calling GMP from Zig

Tags: zig

I'm new to Zig and wanted to use the cImport to call out to the GNU Multiprecision library GMP.  I got this to work but it feels awkward because Zig apparently doesn't cast from arrays to pointers by default and GMP uses this approach to pass by reference.  Is there a cleaner approach than mine?  Are there existing examples of Zig calling GMP?

```
const gmp = @cImport({
    @cInclude("gmp.h");
});

pub fn main() void {
    var x: gmp.mpz_t = undefined;
    gmp.mpz_init(&x[0]);
    gmp.mpz_set_ui(&x[0], 7);
    gmp.mpz_mul(&x[0], &x[0], &x[0]);
    _ = gmp.gmp_printf("%Zd\n", x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to drop the `[0]`:

```
const gmp = @cImport({
    @cInclude("gmp.h");
});

pub fn main() void {
    var x: gmp.mpz_t = undefined;
    gmp.mpz_init(&x);
    gmp.mpz_set_ui(&x, 7);
    gmp.mpz_mul(&x, &x, &x);
    _ = gmp.gmp_printf("%Zd\n", x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's cleaner.  I hadn't fully appreciated the difference from C where &array would return a double pointer.